# Decimal to Binary Signed in C++

Tags: c++

This is what I have:

```
string decimal_to_binary(int n){
string result = "";
while(n > 0){
    result = string(1, (char) (n%2 + 48)) + result;
    n = n/2;
}
return result; }
```

This works, but it doesn't work if I put a negative number, any help?

Comment: Check for negative values of `n` and take appropriate action. What do you want the function to do with negative values?

Comment: Please clarify your question.. where do you "put" the negative number in this? If `n` is negative then `while (n > 0)` fails to enter and so you return an empty string. Is that what you intended?  It would be better to post a [MCVE](http://stackverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces some output, and explain how the output differs from what you wanted.

Comment: @M.M - Yes, n is my value. I just realized that I had the n > 0. Do I need an if statement to separate negatives from positive ints ?

Comment: That would be one option, but you still haven't shown what behaviour you want to result for negative `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would recommend calling a separate function for negative numbers. Given that, for example, -1 and 255 will both return 11111111. Converting from the positive to the negative would be easiest instead of changing the logic entirely to handle both.

Going from the positive binary to the negative is just running XOR and adding 1.

You can modify your code like this for a quick fix.

```
string decimal_to_binary(int n){
    if (n<0){ // check if negative and alter the number
        n = 256 + n;
    }
    string result = "";
    while(n > 0){
        result = string(1, (char) (n%2 + 48)) + result;
        n = n/2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: can you do the same with 32 bit?

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
#include <bitset>
```

Then use **bitset** and **to_string** to convert from int to string

```
std::cout << std::bitset<sizeof(n)*8>(n).to_string();
```

It works for negative numbers too.

Answer (score 0):

> This works, but it doesn't work if I put a negative number, any help?

Check whether the number is negative. If so, call the function again with `-n` and return the concatenated result.

You also need to add a clause to check against 0 unless you want to return an empty string when the input is 0.

```
std::string decimal_to_binary(int n){
   if ( n < 0 )
   {
      return std::string("-") + decimal_to_binary(-n);
   }

   if ( n == 0 )
   {
      return std::string("0");
   }

   std::string result = "";
   while(n > 0){
      result = std::string(1, (char) (n%2 + 48)) + result;
      n = n/2;
   }
   return result;
}
```